# Word document not displaying header, footer and images when using WordProcessingDocument

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, memorystream

I am using `WordprocessingDocument` to Read and write content to a word document but when I am opening the document using `MemoryStream`, it is not showing me the images and header/footer which is already in the word document. Below is the code for the same.

```
private void AddReport(MainDocumentPart parent, MemoryStream report)
        {
            using (MemoryStream editingMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                report.Position = 0;
                report.CopyTo(editingMemoryStream);
                editingMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (WordprocessingDocument newDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(editingMemoryStream, true))
                {
                    WP.Body Template = newDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    var Main = newDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                    var cloneTemplate = Template.CloneNode(true);

                    parent.Document.Body.PrependChild(new WP.Paragraph(new WP.Run(cloneTemplate)));
                    parent.Document.Save();
                }
            }
        }
```

Screenshot for the word document:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbB6O.png)
In this, the Parent document is the document where I am pre-pending the above document. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The headers, footers and images are not part of the document body, so won't be carried over to another document in the described scenario.

All this information is stored in separate "xml parts" contained within the Word file's "zip package". The `Body` part contains only *refereces* (relationship IDs listed in a "rel" part that point/link to the relevant xml part contained in the package).

This can be seen by opening the document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and inspecting the underlying Word Open XML.

In order to copy such content to another document it's necessary to clone not only the body, but also each and every relevant xml part with content you want to have, while dynamically generating the necessary relationships - not a trivial undertaking. There are posts here and elsewhere in the Internet (including my blog, the WordMeister) that demonstrate the basics of how this is done which you could use as starting points for understanding the required approach.

Or, depending on what the Parent document is, it might make more sense to start with a copy of the "new" document and edit it with the other content.

FWIW and mentioned here for the sake of completeness: The COM object model will do what is described - copy the body of the document and paste to another document does carry over all this information. But the Word application is doing all the "heavy lifting" that the developer needs to code when using the Open XML SDK.